# rightBarButtonItem showing on all Simulator but not showing on physical iPhone5 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios-simulator, uibarbuttonitem

I have created the following `rightBarButtonItem` of a animated heart-shaped fav icon. It is showing on the simulator devices, Iphone SE, 8-plus, X. But when I connect to my iPhone5 physical device, it is not showing at all.

`rightBarButtonItem` fav icon showing on simulator iPhoneX

[image: pic]

On iPhone 5 physical device, it is missing but the leftBarButtonItem with the back button is OK on all devices.

[image]

I have tried option 1 and option 2 of the code but still the same, missing on physical device iPhone5

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIButton *heart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    if ([sURL rangeOfString:@"true"].length > 0){
        [heart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite30px.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [heart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite30px.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [heart addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    heart.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(11.0, 0.0, -11.0, 0.0);

    //--- Option 1
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:heart];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = jobsButton;

    //--- Option 2
    // self.btnFav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:heart];

    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.btnFav;
}

-(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton*)heart{
    if( [[heart imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite30px.png"]]) {
        [heart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite30px.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:0.0
                                  animations:^{
                                      [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.10 animations:^{
                                          heart.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
                                      }];
                                      [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.15 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                                          heart.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                                      }];
                                  } completion:nil];
    } else {
        [heart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite30px.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:0.0
                                  animations:^{
                                      [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.10 animations:^{
                                          heart.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
                                      }];
                                      [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.15 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                                          heart.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                                      }];
                                  } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

## Debug View Hierachy

## iPhone 5s SIMULATOR, the FAV icon is showing at Navigation Bar

[image: iPhone5s Simulator]

## iPhone 5 DEVICE, the FAV icon is  missing at Navigation Bar

[image]

Comment: Check if the navigation bar you are refereing to is not nil on the device

Comment: How can it be nil, the leftBarButtonItem is showing, the back button.

Comment: Check using `Debug View Hierarchy` to debug, it'll give you some idea

Comment: try     self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonIcon then.

Comment: Hi Gokul, I have added the `Debug View Hierarchy` but not sure what to look for. Please help.

Comment: added this `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = jobsButton;` but not working

Comment: @Gokul, Please help if possible. I am really stuck.

Comment: @HansheungCheah i have created a sample project with your code. But it works fine. Even in physical device (5s OS 11.2).

Comment: You too just create a sample project and check navigation bar. It may give you some idea